# Handle multiple gmail accounts

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I am using Google Calendar JavaScript API.It works fine for single account.Problem is when user is logged-in into two of my gmail accounts, It asks user every time to select which account user want to use.

I want API to remember my last selection at least for the session or most preferably till user disconnect himself.

Here is my JS file.

```js
var clientId = $("#CalendarClientId").val();


var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';
var objEventList = [];
var calendarIdAtt;

function InitilizeCalendarAPI() {
    // Step 2: Reference the API key
    window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 5);
}
function CheckGoogleCalAuth() {
    
    gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: clientId, scope: scopes }, HandleAuthCallBack);
}
function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: clientId, scope: scopes }, HandelCalAuthResult);
}
function CheckAuthentication() {
    gapi.auth.checkSessionState({ client_id: clientId }, CheckAuthCallback);
}
function CheckAuthCallback(loginDataCallback) {
    
    if (loginDataCallback == false) {
        
        checkAuth();
        $("#googleAuthorize-Button").hide();
    }
}
function HandelCalAuthResult(authResult) {
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        /*authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';*/
        $("#googleAuthorize-Button").hide();
        if ($("#googleConnected").length > 0) {
            $("#googleConnected").show();
        }
        /*bind listing of google calendar name in addevent page*/
        if ($("#divGoogleCalendarNameList").length > 0) {
            GetListOfCalendarNameFromGoogle();
        }
    } else {
        $("#googleAuthorize-Button").show();
        /*authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';*/
        if ($("#googleConnected").length > 0) {
            $("#googleConnected").hide();
        }
    }
    if ($('#googleAuthorized-Button').length > 0) {
        $("#googleAuthorize-Button").hide();
        $('#googleAuthorized-Button').show();
        $('#calenderSettingIcon').attr('data-original-title', 'Connected To Google');
    }
}

function CheckAutheForEventList() {
    
    gapi.auth.checkSessionState({ client_id: clientId }, CheckAuthCallbackListEvent);
}

function CheckAuthCallbackListEvent(loginDataCallback)
{
     gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: clientId, scope: scopes }, LoadEventListinAPI);
}

function checkAuthEventList() {
    ConfirmConnectionToGoogleCalendar(function (isConnect) {        
            if (isConnect) {
                gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: clientId, scope: scopes },             LoadEventListinAPI);
            }
        });
}

function LoadEventListinAPI() {
    
    gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', GetAllCalendar);
}

function GetAllCalendar() {
    gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', GetCalendarAndTheirEvents);
}

function GetCalendarAndTheirEvents() {
    
    objEventList = [];
    try {        
        var objDate = GetMinAndMaxDate();
        var finalMinDate = (objDate.MinDate).toISOString();;
        var finalMaxDate = (objDate.MaxDate).toISOString();;

        var request = gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list();        
        var tempCount = 0;
        request.execute(function (resp) {
            
            var calLength = resp.items.length;
            $.each(resp.items, function (index, item) {
                if (item.accessRole == "owner") {
                    try {
                        calendarIdAtt = item.id;
                        var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
                            'calendarId': item.id,
                            'showDeleted': false,
                            'singleEvents': true,
                            'orderBy': 'startTime',
                            'maxResults': 100,
                            'timeMin': finalMinDate,
                            'timeMax': finalMaxDate
                        });

                        request.execute(function (resp) {
                            tempCount = tempCount + 1;
                            var events = resp.items;
                            if (events.length > 0) {
                                objEventList.push(events);
                            }
                            if (tempCount == calLength) {
                                //Binding Kendo Scheduler with Google Calenda Events
                                var eventsList = BindEventToCalendar();
                                LoadEventsScheduler(eventsList);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    catch (error) {
                        tempCount = tempCount + 1;
                        if (tempCount == calLength) {
                            BindEventToCalendar();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    tempCount = tempCount + 1;
                    if (tempCount == calLength) {
                        BindEventToCalendar();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        return objEventList;
    }
    catch (exception) {
        BindEventToCalendar();
        return null;
    }
}

//Function will display google calendar events in the Kendo Scheduler
function LoadEventsScheduler(eventsList) {
    
    //This will retrun all the google calendar events to the server side for the scheduler
    var request = {
        EventsList: eventsList, CalendarAccount: calendarIdAtt
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(request),
        url: $_SetEventScheduler,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            var data;
            if (msg.hasOwnProperty("d")) {
                data = msg.d;
            }
            else
                data = msg;
            if (data.success) {
                $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler").dataSource.read();
            }
            else {

            }
        }
    });
}
```

I noticed that API show me logged in but calendar is not stored in case of multiple accounts,so it asks me again to select the account.

**Summary:** I want to save the complete scenario (may be calendar_id or any unique identifier) which can tell API which account and which calendar should be picked up.

If you need more details, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply used the auth2 implementation and it is working perfect. 
Basically current session state function do not work properly in old API. That's why it was asking every time for selecting the account and calendar.